# why I cannot get the url parameter with jsf?

Tags: java, jsf

I use jsf 1.x. I do not understand where I am wrong with my code.

**faces-config.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>mainNavigationParametersHandlerBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.test.MainNavigationParametersHandlerBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
   <property-name>userType</property-name>
   <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
   <value>#{param.userType}</value>
  </managed-property>
 </managed-bean>
```

**My bean:**

package com.test;

```
public class MainNavigationParametersHandlerBean {
    // url parameters
    private String userType = "";

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }
}
```

And **my jsp page** (actually it uses content from jsf files):

```
<jsp:root
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    version="1.2">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>   
        <jsp:forward page="/WEB-INF/jsf/userapp-main.jsf" />        
    </body>
</jsp:root>
```

In the userapp-main.jsf I have a header where I want to print out the userType parameter's value for this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/index-userapp.jsp?userType=grav
```

but, in my xhtml page, `#{mainNavigationParametersHandlerBean.userType}` seems to be empty...

Do you see why?

Thanks.

Comment: To what pattern is your faces servlet mapped? Did you check that the managed bean itself gets initialized (for example by putting a println in its constructor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rightclick the opened page in browser and choose *View Source*. Do you see the generated HTML output of JSF tags or the unparsed JSF tags plain among the HTML? I'll bet that it's the latter.

Your JSP approach is a bit weird. I'd just put the contents of `userapp-main.jsp` page inside the `index-userapp.jsp` page and call the page by an URL which matches the URL pattern of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml`. If it is for example `*.jsf`, then you need to open the page by http://localhost:8080/index-userapp.jsf?userType=grav.

I'd also consider upgrading if there is room. JSP 1.2 is quite ancient (10 years old already), it's currently at 2.2 and its successor, Facelets, has already taken its place in Java EE 6 which was released almost 1.5 years ago.